# Setting an audio source to a variable

Tags: javascript

So I was wondering if something like this is possible in javascript.

```
<audio id="audio">
    <source src="yourAudio.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
<script type="text/javaScript">
var alarm = document.getElementById("audio");
//This basically sets the value of the audio to this variable

//So that I can do something like this
alarm.play();

alarm.pause();
</script>
```

This method does not work, I have tried it already. But is there any other JS wizardry that could emulate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will work if you add the `src` to the `audio` tag:

HTML:

```
<audio id="audiotag" src="your_file.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('audiotag').play();
```

Comment: I tired this -copied and pasted exactly. Unfortunatley this does not work, code crashes.

Comment: Doesn't run in browser, don't know console error stuff

Comment: Turns out, you cannot just play audio in JS without a function call? I put this inside a function and made a button. Now it works!

Answer (score 2):

One alternative is to create an `object` of type `Audio` like this:

```
var alarm = new Audio('yourAudio.mp3');
alarm.play();   // you can then invoke the play method
alarm.pause();  // you can then invoke the pause method
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<audio id="audio" src="yourAudio.mp3" ></audio>

 var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
 audio.play();
```

[awesome audio javascript resource](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VuN8qwZoego)